# Why doesn't I/O redirection work when killing background jobs?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

```
[~]$ kill %123

bash: kill: %123: no such job

[~]$ kill %123 2>&1 > /dev/null

bash: kill: %123: no such job
```

I want to disable all output during killing background jobs.

The first output is expected. However, the second output is not.

As showed in the command line, I add `2>&1` to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, and use `> /dev/null` to redirect all output to null device.  But the output is still showed on the terminal.

Any explanations?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated Information:**

The following command works as expected:

```
kill %123 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output redirection is a property of the process. Therefor when redirecting with 2>&1 this sets the *current* output of stdout to stderr which is the current TTY then the following > sets the stdout to /dev/null which leaves stderr set to the TTY. In your updated information you've correctly set the stdout first so both end up being /dev/null.